# I have a this slider, but I want a add div background color after a .current class div (3rd one)

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider current"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

I have a this slider, but I want a add div background color after a .current class div (3rd one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No JavaScript necessary. Just use CSS with `.slider.current + .slider` to select the div after the one with `.current`

Example:

```css
.slider.current+.slider {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">slider</div>
<div class="slider current">slider current</div>
<div class="slider">slider</div>
<div class="slider">slider</div>
<div class="slider">slider</div>
<div class="slider">slider</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to add a background color to the third div,
you can add a simple script to solve this. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[2].style.background = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one approach using CSS, HTML and vanilla JavaScript to highlight the currently selected `div`. You can select the `div` by clicking on it.

One could also implement a solution using [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

```js
function setCurrent(newCurrent) {
  // select the currently active div
  const current = document.querySelector(".slider.current");
  // if it's the one that's already active, there is nothing to do
  if (newCurrent == current) return
  // we need to change the currently selected div
  // remove "current" class and update text of current div
  current.classList.remove("current");
  current.textContent = "Slider";
  // add "current" class and set text for now current div
  newCurrent.classList.add("current")
  newCurrent.textContent = "Current";
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  // add on click listener to all elements with the a class "slider"
  document.querySelectorAll(".slider").forEach((slider) => {
    slider.addEventListener("click", () => setCurrent(slider));
  })
})
```

```css
.slider {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/* more specific rule for elements with class slider and current*/

.slider.current {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">Slider</div>
<div class="slider current">Current</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextSibling` like so:

```
document.querySelector('.slider').nextSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```